# MEF import part local configuration context

Tags: c#, .net, mef

My goal is to set up dependency injection such that the configuration file pertaining to any particular composed part is used instead of the configuration of the container. 
In other words:

Project 1: PluginBase

Project 2:

- `PluginImplementation : PluginBase`
- constructor:

> ```
> public PluginImplementation()
> {
>     var myConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myConfigSection");
> }
> ```

- App.config

Project 3:

- PluginContainer
- App.config

Normally, when "Project 3" calls `PluginContainer.ComposeParts`, the constructor `PluginImplementation()` is called and the implied source of `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myConfigSection")` is Project 3->App.config.

Can this behavior be changed so that the source is Project **2**->App.Config?